# Orientation of image using a reference image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on image similarity-based defect detection, where I am comparing two images.

Reference image:

[image: 1]

Test image

[image: 2]

I am stuck in a problem where the image is oriented a little, I get defects in that too, as the above images are pretty much aligned but I still get defects which should not be highlighted. I can't find a way to orient the image based on reference image accurately. Below is the result and code I have used for image similarity and defect detection.

```
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load images
before = cv2.imread('assets/ref.png')
after = cv2.imread('assets/test1.png')

# Convert images to grayscale
before_gray = cv2.cvtColor(before, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
after_gray = cv2.cvtColor(after, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Compute SSIM between the two images
(score, diff) = structural_similarity(before_gray, after_gray, full=True)
print("Image Similarity: {:.4f}%".format(score * 100))

diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
diff_box = cv2.merge([diff, diff, diff])

thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 50, 50, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

mask = np.zeros(before.shape, dtype='uint8')
filled_after = after.copy()

for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 40:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(before, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(after, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(diff_box, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], 0, (255,255,255), -1)
        cv2.drawContours(filled_after, [c], 0, (0,255,0), -1)

cv2.imwrite('diff.png', diff)
cv2.imwrite('diff_box.png', diff_box)
cv2.imwrite('mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite("filled_after.png", filled_after)
```

Mask

[image: 3]

Differences:

[image: 4]

Comment: try `cv::FindTransformECC()`